# issue with getting querySelectorAll to work in lit-element 2.0 element

Tags: javascript, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I am working with lit-element 2.0 and I am having an issue where I am getting an error code

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined

this is the code that is generating the error

```
        console.log(this._root.querySelectorAll("input"))
        var elements = this._root.querySelectorAll("input");
        for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
            if(elements[i].type == "text"){
                elements[i].value = "";
            }
        }
```

what I am trying to do is get all the input elements of my form and clear them out this should be working and I do not understand why it is not. Still new to lit-element and javascript.

any help would be great.

Comment: where is `_root` defined ? what is `this` in this context. The problem is not your querySelectorAll but rather the object you are trying to scope on is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

After some extensive research I have fixed the issue _root was deprecated in the newer version of lit-element I was able to solve it by using this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll now my app is working as intended . thank you for your time and help